# Which AWS service to use for my large MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds

I currently have 1 big app using a AWS RDS MySQL database. All my tables are small, but there is one large table with over 12M rows that will keep growing, that i'd like to separate into something else. This table is used for reporting and analytics.

I have thought about the following options:

- create another RDS DB for just that big table
- switch the DB to an Amazon Aurora cluster and use a read replica just for that big table
- move the big table to a DynamoDB table
- move the big table to Redshift
- move the big table to ElasticSearch

What would you guys suggest?

Thank you!

Comment: What are the operations that you are planning to use on the Table? What is the allowed latency - are you okay to wait 5/10 minutes to get a response or you want it instantaneous?

Comment: I am doing large queries for generating charts, paginated queries for generating tables, maybe even non-paginated queries for generating large tables. Allowed latency is 1-2 seconds, can't afford to wait 5/10 minutes.

Comment: 12 million rows is not large, it's not even medium size. Did you even measure if RDS can't keep up with the demand? It's extremely important what kind of operations you're doing and how much data is being moved around. If you blindly think that sticking records in another database/nosql will help - no, it won't. All of them deal with the same problem using the same algorithm. No one can tell *how* you're performing analytics or if you're using techniques that help avoid I/O. Unless you get detailed about it, you'll get a suggestion that will possibly set you to wrong path.

Comment: I agree with @N.B. 12 MB is not too big. You can still select the size of underlying EC2 instance and with compression you can save a lot of space. Are you going to get 12MB of data per sec/hour/day? DynamoDB coding will get complex if you try to replace MySQL. Redshift/Elastic Search is Faster but the cost will be higher as they need a cluster.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. But i will try to explain and give you more insight of what's going on. The application i have is a call tracking app, meaning it is receiving calls, like hundreds of calls per hour. The big table i am talking about is the "calls" table. Sometimes when someone is running a report on the calls table, fetching calls for a year or more, or when i apply an index to the table, or when i need to run an update query, some calls that come in are failing, because of waiting on other queries to finish. Calls need to always come in and never fail, so i want to separate things.

Comment: Applying an index on the table is not something you should be doing often. It's an action that's nearly always defined when creating the table - and if you need to do it often, it's a sign of bad design. The approach that would be correct, no matter what database vendor you use, is to have transaction processing database/table and analytics processing database/table. It means you should have one table where you insert the calls and the other table that you use to run analytics off of. Common techniques include running calculations at point of insertion and storing the result (materialization).

Comment: Yeah i know, i was just giving some examples. Ok, i like that idea. I am thinking, what if the analytics table is even in a different database? Since i am using AWS, that will be easy to manage. And should it be a whole different database, or Aurora with read replica?

Comment: That different database can be whatever you want - totally different database vendor, a different instance of RDS, whatever makes it easier for you to deal with. All that matters is that you don't use 1 glass that 2 people use to drink at the same time

Comment: Ok, makes perfect sense. What do you think is best? Just different tables in the same DB? Or completely separate DB for the analytics table?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the 10-15 calls per second (1000 per hour) comment you can set it up on DynamoDB. It is cheaper and faster writes. I have faced issues in high throughput writes to MySQL unless they are properly orchestrated. DDB will give you enough room to grow easily. This approach is easier if you have less time to develop.

DDB:
PrimaryKey - Phone [Number], SortKey - Call Start Time In Epoch MS [Number]

Now based on your queries -

- if they are about calls from a number: your APIs have to fetch it from DDB.
- you might have to setup DDB streams or hourly aggregates table in MySQL which stores the aggregated data.

This will make your reports run faster and persist/update the call records faster. Incase you need accurate information regarding a particular call - make sure you use consistent reads from DDB.

On the contrary -

I had tested, MySQL can write up to 24,000 records per-second consistently using batch write. This was a dual core laptop test. ec2s can be smaller. The benchmark is much higher. If you plan to use MySQL, you have to manage the batch. Buffer the call records and batch update in an interval. Make sure each transaction commits.  This will give you more aggregate capability for reporting.

Comment: I need to query by multiple things, not just by number. But also by campaign, duration. which number called, which number received the call, call status, spam/not spam, etc.. Based on that, which option do you think is better? Still DDB or MySQL?

Comment: Usually when you are doing reporting it is better to go with a relational database like MySQL. In that case you can also integrate the DB directly with reporting tools like Tableau which will be able to create and run queries in the backend. On the Contrary with DynamoDB you will need indexes for each search and then aggregate them on your own - increasing the time to build the reports.

Comment: Thank you, i really appreciate your input, this helped me a lot.